# T4 Font encoding

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

This is an excerpt of a script I found and I have a question about the font.

[image]

I think for this type you need the command

`\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}`

I tried applying this and the result was almost perfect, the only problem was that the words that were bold, for example in `\section{Introduction}`, were not bold at all. They looked like this in my output

[image]

My explicit question: How can one use African Latin (T4) font so that the boldness is not affected (like in the script)? What are the right packages or commands?

Here is a zoomed in version

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what exactly are you asking? Do you have a source? How did you obtain this picture? Why should you want to use a legacy encoding for African letters?

Comment: why T4 rather than the standard western european T1 encoding? Or even the obsolete but still default OT1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My motives are not relevant, I just want to know it for fun. I like this font.

Comment: the letter shapes are likely to be the same in any case, but T4 is a specialist encoding with a much reduced font support so fine if you want it but not having font variants such as bold is to be expected.  That said, `t4cmr.fd` _does_ declare bold variants

Comment: Note that T4 is an _encoding_ not a particular font, so whether bold is available depends on the font you are using, and you have provided no example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok now I understand the issue. Thanks. Dou you recommend a font?

Comment: you are just using the default computer modern aren't you?

Answer (score 1):

On an up-to-date TeX Live 2022, the only supported fonts for the T4 encoding are a variant of Courier that can be loaded with `\renewcommant\familydefault{fcr}`, and the default Computer Modern family. All of these produce Type 3 bitmap fonts that will come out as pixelated in a PDF.  Since nobody rasterizes LaTeX documents to DVI and prints them out on paper any longer, I would not recommend you use this encoding today.  If you need the glyphs for one of the languages it supports, you could get better output from a Unicode font in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  More to the point, your image does not appear to have been generated with `\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}`.

I am not sure on what basis you believe this document used that encoding.  I am unaware of any other German documents that do.  If you are looking at a list of fonts and seeing their formats displayed as “Type 1” or “Type 3,” keep in mind that these are Adobe PostScript font identities, totally unrelated to the LaTeX encodings from the 1990s called T1, T2A, T3, and so on.

I also cannot reproduce your bug with the bold fonts on an up-to-date TeX Live 2022.  The header displays (in an obsolete format) just fine for me with `\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}`.

Comment: So you say the document I presented is not encoded in T4? Then I ask myself what kind of encoded was used...

Comment: @calculatormathematical It would be possible to tell by examining the bytes of the file, but probably either Cork encoding or Unicode.

Comment: I added a zoomed in version and it looks like african latin

Comment: @calculatormathematical The zoomed-in version shows that this document uses a Type-3 bitmap font. My guess would be that this document was created using T1 or OT1 encoding using a METAFONT version of Computer Modern, on a very old or misconfigured installation, or by compiling the document to DVI and then converting that to PDF. However, T4 encoding is possible.